# IAM policy to allow access to a specific version of an object in S3 object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have three versions of an object in a bucket. I am trying to create an IAM role such that the user can only access one specific version of that object. This is my policy so far :-

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucketVersions"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObjectVersion",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/photo.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "s3:GetObjectVersion",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/photo.jpg",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:VersionId": "X9R5gJiVUszzxtlsBdMi_cfvftr43"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I run `aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket my-bucket --prefix photo.jpg` in the cli, I'm still getting the output with all three versions of the file when I should just get one which is specified in the policy. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am i doing wrong?

Nothing. That's how it should work. `list-object-versions` list **all** object versions, exactly as it is supposed to do. You can't limit it to only list selected versions and "hide" other versions.

If you do not like that behavior, do not allow `ListBucketVersions`.

Comment: For reference, if you look in [Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon S3 - Service Authorization Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html), you'll notice that `ListBucketVersions` has a list of `Conditions`. These conditions can be used to limit the permission being granted. However, the actual versions of an object are _not_ listed in the Conditions, so it cannot be used to limit the listing. In contrast, `Prefix` is listed so it _can_ be used to limit the listing.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I was making the wrong api call, i had to instead use `get-object` and not `list-object-versions`.